# Get data grouped by weeks

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to count count rows numbers grouped by week as follow

```
    SELECT count(*) AS count, week(creating_date,1) AS week
    FROM USERS 
    GROUP BY week(creating_date,1)
```

but it count weeks in which users were added.I want to get report for each week and if no user was added it should returns 0.

Comment: You need a help table containing all possible weeks.

Comment: As I said, create a help table for the weeks (and insert values into it.) Then do a JOIN and do same group by etc as now.

Comment: You don't *need* a help table containing all possible weeks, but that is one way of solving this - and it would be an OUTER JOIN, if adopting that method.

Comment: How can I fill it with weeks number ?